# Identify SMD transistor - top marking Al PE..?

Tags: transistors, identification, surface-mount

[image]I need to know the specifications of the transistor that burn out in orange circle on my battery charger. Top markings on 3 other transistors from other 3 working charging circuits seem to be something like Al PE..???
[image]
[image]

Comment: Check [here](https://s-manuals.com/smd/). For marking **AI** there's nothing in SOT-23 case. There are some NPN transistors for marking **AL** but the marking is not completely readable, so I couldn't be sure.

Comment: Am I the only person who thinks the solder on that transistor could do with being added to, particularly to improve its heat dissipation and prevent its untimely demise?

Comment: Thanks Rohat. I will try to get a better shot to confirm marking